# Script to upgrade / downgrade SQL Azure Database to /from Standard and Premium service levels

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-sql-database

I have a SQL Azure database which requires a Premium (P1) service level during business hours but could be downgraded to Standard (S2) during night and Week-ends for cost saving purposes.

I can perform these operations through the Azure management portal without any problem but wanted to do it by the mean of a scheduled powershell script.

Basically, my script is doing the following (extract) :

```
$db = Get-AzureSqlDatabase $serverContext –DatabaseName $dbName
$P1 = Get-AzureSqlDatabaseServiceObjective $serverContext -ServiceObjectiveName "P1"
Set-AzureSqlDatabase $serverContext –Database $db –ServiceObjective $P1 -Force
```

Unfortunately, it seems to be forbidden to perform this operation through script :-(

```
*Set-AzureSqlDatabase : The edition 'Standard' does not support the service objective '7203483a-c4fb-4304-9e9f-17c71c904f5d'.*
```

Does anyone know if this is a limitation of the SQLAzure cmdlet or if I'm doing something wrong (I do not have any troubles submitting the same request through the portal). Is there a better way to automate these upgrade/downgrade operations on schedule (REST API ?)?

Thanks for your help

Oliver

Comment: not sure if this causes the error but the `-ServiceObjectiveName` in Microsofts example is `" P1"`, they also use the switch `-Edition Premium`.
Here´s the link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn369872.aspx

Comment: Thank you @Paul ! Shame on me, after much refactoring on the code I somehow forgot the -Edition flag ! The leading space in " P1" does not change anything, but the -Edition flag seems to be mandatory when switching between Premium and Standard (which makes sense actually). Unfortunately I don't manage to credit you for this answer

Comment: no problem :) i have added it as answer

Answer (score 3):

Your call to `Set-AzureSqlDatabase` is missing the `-Edition` parameter.

```
Set-AzureSqlDatabase $serverContext –Database $db –ServiceObjective $P1 -Force -Edition Premium
```